# Sum of the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{5n+\cos n}{3+2n^3}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

The series $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{5n+\cos n}{3+2n^3}\tag 1$$ converges because $$\frac{5n+\cos n}{3+2n^3}\sim_0 \frac 52 \cdot \frac1{n^2} $$
Infact
$$\frac{5n+\cos n}{3+2n^3}=\frac{n\left(5+\frac{\cos n}n\right)}{n^3\left(\frac3{n^3}+2\right)}\sim_\infty\frac 1{n^2}\cdot \frac 52$$

We have

$$\frac{\frac{5n+\cos n}{3+2n^3}}{\frac 52\cdot\frac 1{n^2}}\sim_\infty 1$$

but do have a sum the $(1)$?

Comment: You probably won't find a closed form for the sum. Why would you expect one?

Comment: [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=sum+%285n%2Bcos%28n%29%29%2F%283%2B2n%5E3%29%2C+n%3D1+to+infinity) doesn't give a closed form for the serie, but the formula for the partial sum it's quite...difficult.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I thought: yes. :-)

Comment: @Davide Thank you very much.

Comment: The equivalence you wrote in the fourth line is near infinity. Hello.

Comment: @hamam_Abdallah Ciaoooooooooo...Why? Can you write a comment or an answer? Thank you very much.

Comment: @hamam_Abdallah I hope nothing serious happened. I wish you lots of good luck.

Comment: Thanks a lot dear friend,